# Как получить все данные из SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Как получить все данные из Preferences android из Java кода. Нужны все данные из SharedPreferences в виде двух массивов либо Map.

P.S. Ключи не известны, нужно получить набор ключей и значений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения всех данных в виде `Map<String, ?>` можно воспользоваться методом [`Map<String, ?> getAll ()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll()).

Comment: Благодарю, можно еще вкратце про тип "?" пожалуйста)

Comment: @Maxgmer, Это [*подстановочный тип (wildcard type)*](http://www.k-press.ru/cs/2008/3/generic/generic.asp). Вкратце, боюсь, не получится.